# Request to api without AUTH returns JSON with generic data

Tags: api, activecollab

when we make a request to the collab api without authenticating we receive a JSON with standard values.
For example:
[json value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZHA7.jpg)

Is it possible to eliminate this behaviour and return an error?,
thanks

we have consulted the generic collab configuration from backend and in the generic config.php files, but we don't see any configuration to disable this behaviour.